# Show that $E[X]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $Z$ be a standard normal random variable, and, for a fixed $x$, set

$
X=
\begin{cases}
Z &\text{if } Z>x \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

Show that $\displaystyle E[X]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$

---

**My attempt:**

It looks like $X$ is also a continuous random variable and so if we can find the probability density of $X$ $f_X(x)$, then we can use the formula

$$E[X]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_X(x)\ dx$$

But there's a problem: $\displaystyle P\{X=0\}=P\{Z\le x\}=\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}\ dx>0$

But the probability that a continuous random variable will assume any fixed value is zero. So, $P\{X=0\}\ne 0$ implies that $X$ is not a continuous random variable after all. Have I made a mistake? How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

We have 
$$
E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}X\ p(X)dX = \int_{x}^{\infty} Z\frac{e^{-Z^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dZ = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_x^{\infty} \frac{d}{dZ}e^{-Z^2/2}dZ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}.
$$

Your mistake in calculating $P(X = 0)$ is to assume that $p(X)$ is still Gaussian when $X < x$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}t\ f_X(t)dt = \int_{-\infty}^x tf_X(t) dt + \int_{x}^{\infty} tf_X(t)dt = \int_{x}^{\infty} tf_Z(t)dt = \int_{x}^{\infty} t\frac{e^{-t^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dt \\ 
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{x}^{\infty} te^{-t^2/2}dt = \cdots = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}
$$